# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FieldFile

Tags: python, django, excel

I have these excel sheets which i am getting from the queryset in django rest framework.I converted that to list and want to process the excel file .
Do i need to store it somewhere in my app before reading it or will storing it a variable and reading work fine .
What is the best method to accomplish this ?
What i tried doing is this but it does not seem to be working .

```
excel_data =list(ExcelFiles.objects.all())
    print("excel_data", excel_data)
    for item in excel_data:
        print("item id ", item.id)
        print("item.company is ", item.company)
        print("item again", item.plan_type)
        print("item.excel is ", item.excelFile)
        print("item.status is" ,item.status)
        if item.status == False:
            if hasattr(item,'excelFile'):
                print(item.excelFile)
                excel_sheet=item.excelFile
                wb = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_sheet)// error occurs here
                sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
                print("sheet", sheet)
```

I am using xlrd.

Answer (score 0):

We have no idea what inside the `ExcelFiles.objects.all()`, neither the error you have. I would say there are two things you can do:

1. check what `item.excelFile` is, is it a link? Since you don't want to save it, it's better a link that point to the file.
2. `xlrd` should have a function read from a link, but it must be the *url content*, you could try:

```
import requests
import xlrd
import urllib

link = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SheetJS/test_files/a9c6bbb161ca45a077779ecbe434d8c5d614ee37/AutoFilter.xls'
file_name, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(link)
print (file_name)
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)
print (workbook)
```

Resource: [Open an excel from http website using xlrd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437357/open-an-excel-from-http-website-using-xlrd)

Answer (score 0):

`FieldFile` is a proxy object for accessing the stored file on the server. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile), FieldFile.name

> The name of the file including the relative path from the root of the Storage of the associated FileField.

So you can simply pass the path to the file:

```py
excel_sheet=item.excelFile
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_sheet.name) # pass the path to the file instead
```